# Does "the overall sake" mean "for the sake of the majority of people"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

I was certain that the "phrase" **(the) overall sake** exist until I have typed it on *Google* search box to find no result containing it as a whole.

So, I want to know if it exists in English and if it would mean what I want to convey which is "for the sake of the majority of people".

- I have also searched for a phrase to indicate that meaning but didn't find a one.

For example:

> Even if it wasn't to your approbation, it would be for **the overall sake**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say

- for **everybody's sake**
- for **the sake of everybody**
- for **all our sakes**

Or any smaller group:

- for the **whole team's sake**
- for **both our sakes**
- for **everybody else's sake**
- She did for the **sake of everybody else** (for their benefit)
- She did it for **the sake of everybody but him** (for benefit of others except one)
- She did it for the **sake of everybody but herself** (for benefit of others excluding the one who did the action)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but is there a way to exclude that person from the phrase as it is not for her sake but for the rest's sake?

Comment: Added a few more examples including "She did it for the sake of everybody else" or "sake of everybody but herself"

Answer (score 1):

This is not a typical phrase but you could use something like "For the sake of everyone involved" or "For everyone's sake"...

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you by _typical_ mean that it is incorrect and can't possibly be used?

Comment: what I mean is your original "the overall sake" is not typical. Which means it's not necessarily incorrect however, yes, it is incorrect. Use something like the above answers suggest. @TasneemZH